# Webpack DefinePlugin not replacing text in output

Tags: typescript, webpack

I'm having difficulty getting even a token example of webpack's `DefinePlugin` working. That is, `npx webpack` runs just fine, but the output js files don't have the defined tokens replaced. Here's my minimal (non-)working example:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    // bundling mode
    mode: "development",
    devtool: 'source-map',

    // input file
    entry: "./Index.ts",

    // loaders (e.g. run tsc on *.tsx?)
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "ts-loader",
                }
            },
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            DUMMYVARIABLE: JSON.stringify('helloworld'),
        })
    ],
}
```

Index.ts

```
var DUMMYVARIABLE: string;

export class IndexModel {
    public static GetDummyVariable(): string {
        return DUMMYVARIABLE;
    }
}
```

The output js file (note that DUMMYVARIABLE is still present, rather than being replaced by `'helloworld'` as expected):

```
/******/ (() => { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    "use strict";
var __webpack_exports__ = {};
// This entry need to be wrapped in an IIFE because it uses a non-standard name for the exports (exports).
(() => {
var exports = __webpack_exports__;
/*!******************!*\
  !*** ./Index.ts ***!
  \******************/

exports.__esModule = true;
exports.IndexModel = void 0;
var DUMMYVARIABLE;
var IndexModel = /** @class */ (function () {
    function IndexModel() {
    }
    IndexModel.GetDummyVariable = function () {
        return DUMMYVARIABLE;
    };
    return IndexModel;
}());
exports.IndexModel = IndexModel;

})();

/******/ })()
;
//# sourceMappingURL=main.js.map
```

As far as I  can tell, it's critical to have a file called tsconfig.json, but its contents matter less – at the moment I just have `{}` in there.

Can someone help me understand where I'm going wrong and how to get `DefinePlugin` to work for me?

Hope you'll forgive my rookie webpack-ness, I've been able to treat webpack as a black box previously.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Webpack doesn't replace the `DUMMYVARIABLE` variable with *"helloworld"* because you didn't defined it as global variable, but as a local variable. To make your example work you need to remove the `var DUMMYVARIABLE;` declaration since the occurence in the script makes webpack believe that `DUMMYVARIABLE` is a local variable. Additionally, to prevent type-errors from typescript you should also use [`declare`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/by-example.html#global-variables) to tell typescript that `DUMMYVARIABLE` is global:

```
declare var DUMMYVARIABLE: string;

export class IndexModel {
    public static GetDummyVariable(): string {
        return DUMMYVARIABLE;
    }
}
```

Now the `webpack.DefinePlugin` would replace the occurences like so:

```
var IndexModel = /** @class */ (function () {
    function IndexModel() {
    }
    IndexModel.GetDummyVariable = function () {
        return "helloworld";
    };
    return IndexModel;
}());
```

Comment: Thank you *so much* – I am both shocked and utterly unsurprised that it's something so tiny. To check that I understand this: DefinePlugin only does substitutions on global variables? That's remarkably clever.
Thanks again.

Comment: @Zeph Actually, it's not a function of TypeScript at all. On line 1 of your `index.ts` example, you have `var DUMMYVARIABLE: string;`. This creates a variable called `DUMMYVARIABLE` in the scope. When Webpack sees that `DUMMYVARIABLE` is defined, it decides not to replace it. Instead, if you use `declare var DUMMYVARIABLE: string;`, you're telling TypeScript what kind of variable it is, but not Webpack. So when Webpack is going through your code and doesn't see a `DUMMYVARIABLE` defined, it replaces it with what you specified in your `webpack.DefinePlugin`. --- Wordy reply, but hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info; makes sense to me.

Comment: Thank you, this important bit of information feels like its nowhere else on the internet. I was getting intermittent success without it, which was strangeer than no success at all